# Best .Net Actor/Process framework for coordinating Local and Networked clusters

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric, actor, akka.net

We have a process that involves loading a large block of data, applying some transformations to it, and then outputting what has changed. We currently run a web app where multiple instances of these large blocks of data are processed in the same CLR instance, and this leads to garbage collection thrashing and OOM errors.

We have proven that hosting some tracked state in a longer running process works perfectly to solve our main problem. The issue we now face is, as a stateful system, we need to host it and manage coordination with other parts of the system (also change tracking instances).

I'm evaluating Actors in Service Fabric and Akka at the moment, there are a number of other options, but before I proceed, I would like peoples thoughts on this approach with the following considerations:

- We have a natural partition point in our system (Authority) which means we can divide our top level data set easily. Each partition will be represented by a top level instance that needs to organise a few sub-actors in its own local cluster, but we would expect a single host machine to be able to run multiple clusters.
- Each Authority Cluster of actors would ideally be hosted together on a single machine to benefit from local communication and some use of shared local resources to get around limits on message size.
- The actors themselves should be separate processes on the same box (Akka seems to run local Actors in the same CLR instance, which would crash everything on OOM - is this true?), this will enable me to spin up a process, run the transformation through it, emit the results and tear it down without impacting the other instances memory / GC. I appreciate hardware resource contention would still be a problem, but I expect this to be more memory than CPU intensive, so expect a RAM heavy box.
- Because the data model is quite large, and the messages can contain either model fragments or changes to model fragments, it's difficult to work with immutability. We do not want to clone every message payload into internal state and apply it to the model, so ideally any actor solution used would enable us to work with the original message payload. This may cause problems with restoring an actor state as it wants to save and replay these on wakeup, but as we have state tracking internally, we can just store the resulting output of this on sleep.
- We need a coordinator that can spin up instances of an Authority Cluster. There needs to be some elasticity in terms of the number of VM's/Machines and the number of Authority Clusters hosted on them, and something needs to handle creation and destruction of these.
- We have a *lot* of .NET code, all our models, transformations and validation is defined in it, and will need to be heavily re-used. Whatever solution will need to support .Net

My questions then are:

While this feels like a good fit for Actors, I have reservations and wonder if there is something more appropriate? Everything I have tried has come back to a hosted processes of some kind.

If actors are the right way to go, which tech stack would put me closest to what I am trying to achieve with the above concerns taken into account?

Answer (score 1):

IMO (coming at this from a JVM Akka perspective, thus why I changed the `akka` tag to `akka.net`; I don't have a great knowledge about the CLR side of things), there seems to be a mismatch between

> We do not want to clone every message payload into internal state and apply it to the model, so ideally any actor solution used would enable us to work with the original message payload.

and

> The actors themselves should be separate processes on the same box (Akka seems to run local Actors in the same CLR instance, which would crash everything on OOM - is this true?)

Assuming that you're talking about the same OS process, those are almost certainly mutually incompatible: exchanging messages strongly suggests serialization and is thus isomorphic to a copy operation.  It's possible that something using shared memory between OS processes could work, but you may well have to make a choice about which is more important.

Likewise, the parent/child relationship in the "traditional" (Erlang/Akka) style actor model trivially gives you the local cluster of actors (which, since they're running in the same OS process allows the Akka optimization of not copying messages until you cross an OS process boundary), while "virtual actor" implementations as found in Service Fabric or Orleans (or, I'd argue Cloudstate or Lagom) basically assume distribution.

Semantically, the virtual actor models implicitly assume that actors are eternal (though their eternal essence may not always be incarnate).  For your use-case, this doesn't necessarily seem to be the case.

I think a cluster of Akka.Net instances with sharded `Authority` actors spawning shorter-lived child actors best fits, assuming that you're getting OOM issues from trying to process multiple large blocks of data simultaneously.  You would have to implement the instance scale-up/down logic yourself.

Comment: To clarify regarding the cloning - I meant the duplication of the message received (to replay) and the model fragment that it contains (to add to the model and mutate). Given the potential volume, doubling everything received would be too expensive, hence keeping it mutable and dropping it straight into the central state. It's effectively a large document host.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with Akka.net so I can't speak to that at all, but I'd be happy to speak to what you're talking about in a Service Fabric context.

- Service Fabric has no issue with the concept of running multiple clusters. In its terminology, the whole of your system would be called an Application and would have a version when deployed to the SF cluster. If you wanted to create multiple instances of it, all you'd need to do is select what you wanted to call the deployed app instance and it'll stand up provisioning for you.
- SF has a notion of [placement constraints, metric balancing and custom rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-configure-services) that you can utilize if you think you can better balance the various resources than its automatic balancing (or you need to for network DMZ purposes). While I've never personally grouped things down to a single machine, I frequently limit access of services to single VM scale sets (we host in Azure).
- To the last point though, you'll still have message size limits, but you can also [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.fabrictransport.fabrictransportremotingsettings.maxmessagesize) them to some degree. In your project containing service interfaces, just set the following attribute above your namespace:
  `[assembly:FabricTransportRemotingSettings(MaxMessageSize=<(long)new size in bytes>)]` and you're good to go.
- Services can be configured to run using a Shared or Exclusive [process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-hosting-model).
- Regarding your state requirement, it's not necessarily clear to me what you're trying to do, but I *think* you're saying that that it's not critical that your actors store any state since they can work from some centrally-provided model.

You might look then at volatile [state persistence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-state-management) then as it'll mean that state is saved for the actors in memory, but should you lose the replicas, nothing is written to disk so it's all lost. Or if you don't care and are ok just sending the model to the actors for any work, you can configure them to be stateless.

- On the other hand, if you're still looking to retain state in the actors and simply are concerned about immutability, rest assured that actor state isn't immutable and can be updated trivially. There are simply order of operation concerns you need to keep in mind (e.g. if you retrieve the state, make a change, save it, 1) you must commit the transaction for it to take and 2) if you modify the state but don't save it, it'll obviously not persist - pull a fresh copy in a new transaction for any modifications). There's a whole pile of guidelines [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-guidelines).
- Assuming your coordinator is intended to save some sort of state, might I recommend a singleton stateful service. Presumably it's not receiving an inordinate amount of use so a single instance is sufficient and it can easily save state (without the annoyance of identifying which state is on which partition). As for spinning up services, I covered this in the first bullet, but use the ApplicationManager on the built-in [FabricClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications-fabricclient) to set up new applications and the ServiceManager to create instances of necessary services within each.

Service Fabric supports .NET Core 3.1 through .NET 5 as of the latest [8.0 release](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/blob/master/release_notes/Service_Fabric_ReleaseNotes_80.md) though note [a minor serialization](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/1079) issues with an easy workaround with .NET 5.

If you have an Azure support subscription, I'd encourage you to write to the team under Development questions and share your concerns. Alternatively, on the third Thursday of each month at 10 AM PST, they also have a community call on Teams that you're [welcome to join](https://aka.ms/sfcommunityqa) and you can find past calls [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0nFiDDfBO8yhmGV0kgPiNw).

Again, I can't speak to whether this is a better fit than Akka.NET, but our stack is built atop Service Fabric. While it has some shortcomings (what framework doesn't?) it's an excellent platform for distributed software development.